# Which sourcebooks include tattoos (both magical and nonmagical)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

As they are not in the core books I wonder in which books are the definitions for nonmagical and also magical tattoos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Inner Sea World Guide](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/varisian-tattoo) and [Inner Sea Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/inscribe-magical-tattoo-item-creation) both have a feat, while Inner Sea Magic also has a [spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/transfer-tattoo) involving magical tattoos.  Advanced Player's Guide describes a [common tattoo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/containers-bags-boxes-more#TOC-Tattoo), while Ultimate Equipment has a [tattooed holy symbol](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/toys-games-puzzles#TOC-Holy-Symbol) that functions for Clerics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Psionics](http://dreamscarredpress.com/dragonfly/Store/product/pid=126.html) expansions for Pathfinder, take a look at the [Psionic Tattoos](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/psionic-tattoos), which act similar to potions.